# Q: Prove that Cartesian Product is distributive over Minkowski sums

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove the following distributive property?

$\prod\limits_{i}^{n} (A_i \oplus B_i) = (\prod\limits_{i}^{n} A_i) \oplus (\prod\limits_{i}^{n} B_i)$

where $\prod$ means Cartesian Product, $\oplus$ means Minkowski sum, and A, B are sets.

I tried a simple example in a 2-d plane and the equality seems like correct. But I did not find a distribution law like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ such that for all $i$ there are $a_i\in A_i$ and $b_i\in B_i$ such that $x_i=a_i+b_i$. Then $a=(a_1,\cdots, a_n)\in \prod_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $b=(b_1,\cdots, b_n)\in \prod_{i=1}^nB_i$ satsify $a+b=x$. On the other hand, let $a+b=x$, with $a_i\in A_i$ and $b_i\in B_i$ for all $i$. Then, $x_i=a_i+b_i\in A_i\oplus B_i$ for all $i$. So $x\in \prod_{i=1}^n (A_i\oplus B_i)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above answer. It is really useful.  Besides that, I am also wondering if the equality still holds if we change the Minkowski sum to Minkowski difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only confusion for me is the definition of Minkowski difference. I found two kinds of definition. 1. $A \ominus B =\{c| c+B \subseteq A\}$ where $A \ominus B \neq A \oplus (-B)$  2. $A \ominus B = A \oplus -B =\{a-b| a \in A,b \in B\}$     If we use the second definition, the proof  could be exactly as you kindly did. But for the first definition, it may be a different story, right?

Comment: @SiyuanLiu My bad, I thought it was another thing. It's basically the same I did in the answe, though. Write down what it all means and the observe that, since we are talking about direct products, "$\forall b\in\prod_i B_i, \exists a\in\prod_i A_i, \forall i,\ b_i+c_i=a_i$" is the same as "$\forall i, \forall b_i\in B_i,\exists a_i\in A_i,\ b_i+c_i=a_i$".